# Kafka streams - Joining streams when events could happen far apart in time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, event-sourcing, stream-processing

I would like to ask for your advice on how I could put together a solution for the following problem with Kafka Streams.

An application has subjects and lessons, and it fires the following events:

```
LessonCreated      SubjectCreated     LessonAddedToSubject   LessonRemovedFromSubject
 +----------+     +--------------+     ---------------+         +--------------+
 | Id  Hours|     |      Id      |     |Lesson|Subject|         |Lesson|Subject|
 | ---+---- |     +--------------+     +--------------+         +--------------+
 | 25 | 20  |     |      1       |     |  25  |   1   |         |  25  |   1   |
 | 26 | 40  |     |      2       |     |  26  |   1   |         |  26  |   2   |
 | 27 | 10  |     |      3       |     |  26  |   2   |         +------+-------+
 +----+-----+     +--------------+     |  26  |   3   |         
                                       |  27  |   3   |         
                                       |  27  |   1   |         
                                       +------+-------+
```

I would like to implement a stream that would take these streams and join them into the following structure:

```
   LessonSubjectHours
 ---------------------+
 |Lesson|Subject|Hours|
 +--------------------+
 |  26  |  1    | 40  |
 |  26  |  3    | 40  |
 |  27  |  3    | 10  |
 |  27  |  1    | 10  |
 +--------------------+
```

I thought about doing some logic with join operations, but I believe it might not help since KStream-KStream joins appear to be forcibly time-windowed (if I understood correctly). This is due to the fact that lessonCreated, lessonAdded and lessonRemoved events could happen indefinitely far apart in time. Thus, I'm afraid windowed joins might lead to wrong results when one of those events happen too long after the last event containing the same key was emitted.

Doing a full lookup for a join shouldn't be a performance issue though, since these events shouldn't happen too often. But still, I have no clue on how to proceed, assuming it is possible to properly deal with this problem in Kafka Streams. So any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

PS: It is still possible to change the events and the data they contain, in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your data is basically tabular. Hence, I am wondering if reading the topics as `KStream` is actually the right approach and if you should process the data as `KTable`? For this case you can just so table-table joins.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My data is tabular, but I need to keep multiple records with the same key (Lesson), as one lesson could be tied to multiple subjects at the same time. Won't reading the data as a KTable lead to older entries being replaced? Take the data presented above. Lesson 26 was first tied to subject 1. Then it also gets tied to subject 2, but since the data is read as a KTable, the API replaces the first record and "forgets" lesson 26 was tied to subject 1.I think the final table would only contain lesson 26,subject 2,40 hours.Is that really it or have I misunderstood the docs?

Comment: Your understanding is correct: KTables require a primary key and you cannot store two records with the same key. Maybe you could read the data a stream, and do an aggregation, that computes a list of subjects per lesson to store the data to work around it?

Comment: That was a great suggestion. My problem has been solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

KTable with local state(RockDb is fast) would be the right choice.

Comment: Would a KTable be able to keep multiple records with the same key? I could be mistaken, but I believe the official documentation states that a KTable event is handled as an upsert operation. So in the case shown above, Lesson 26 is tied to subjects 1, 2 and 3, but the table would only contain Lesson 26 - Subject 3 in its final state, since it would replace older entries of Lesson 26, provided I have the correct understanding.

Comment: it's compact depend on your message's key. so you should use another key for your message instead of Lesson 26